# How to recover accidently deleted partition(s)? -- diskpart > "clean" command issue

Tags: macos, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, testdisk

I've lost 750gb.

Like all those people having the same issue in here, i'd add myself into them by using "clean" command in diskpart during windows installation.

I'm using late 2011 i7 2.2ghz macbookpro with 750gb harddrive. I was going to upgrade win7 to win10 in my 80gb mbr partitioned drive. Than i've converted that partition from mbr to gpt. before that i use only **'clean'** command without **'all'**.

There was there partition like so :
**disk1 / 660gb
disk2 / 80gb
recovery_partition / 2gb**

now, there's no partition listed on boot screen. i have 750gb of unallocated drive. i didn't install any OS. I've tried to quick look at drive with portable ubuntu but it also gave me an error about UEFI.

i found lots of polls, solutions, questions, programs, scripts etc.

what i want to try is creating a new partition about 20gb and OSX in it. try to figure out if is there any partitions left in my drive with **testdisk** and recover files as much as possible.

Problem : i've no partition and volume at the moment and no OS.
Question 1 : is it a bad decision to install an os for now?
Question 2 : is there any other options to check my drives without any OS?

i've lost my last 5 years in 1 second!

I need a third eye.

Thanks,

Lev

Comment: You can run TestDisk from a [live cd](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd) so you don't need to reinstall an OS (at least to recover your partitions).

Comment: @DavidPostill i've formatted my disk and installed and osx.. now test disk is running to find something. but i can still use the live cd right? which one is the right one on that list which you've sent? TestDisk FreeDos LiveCD maybe?

Comment: Don't know, I've never used it.